# Is crypto.js vulnerable to heartbleed attack?

Tags: cryptography, openssl, heartbleed

We are using 'crypto.js' in our application.

Since 'crypto.js' uses open SSL ,are we vulnerable to heartbleeding attack?

If yes, what can we do to prevent it?

Comment: Where does your crypto.js come from?  Are you talking about [this one on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)?

Comment: @Ladadadada We are using version 3.0.2 of cryptojs. We have downloaded from the source mentioned by you.

Answer (score 5):

[Crypto.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) does not *use* OpenSSL, it is interoperable with some of the same algorithms, and is not vulnerable to Heartbleed. All the more so because usually you use crypto.js on the *client*, not on the OpenSSLified server.

Comment: @Iserni Thanks for your prompt reply.Does the mention of 'OpenSSL' in cryptojs.js file make it vulnerable to the attack ,even though it is not being used.

Comment: user44548 - what bit of Iserni's answer confuses you? He has explicitly stated it is not vulnerable.

Comment: @user44548, no, merely "mentioning" a software is not enough to evoke an attack. Even if software engineering *does* sometimes make one think of forbidden magic. Things would be different if the "mentioning" was actually an *executable call*. In this case it is not.

Comment: @user44548 "Does the mention of 'OpenSSL' in cryptojs.js file make it vulnerable to the attack" lol wat?

Comment: Does the mention of OpenSSL in this answer make it vulnerable to heartbleed?

Comment: I feel @user44548 's worry is understandable. The documentation states that `crypto.js` "implements" some OpenSSL algorithms. Without a clear picture of what Heartbleed is and does, it is reasonable to be a bit wary; after all, better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you browse the [Crypto.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/) source, it does not implement TLS (or SSL), and as such can't implement the TLS extension Heartbeats.  By not implementing TLS or Heartbeats, it can't have the Heartbeat vulnerability exploited by Heartbleed (trusting the payload length in a HB request even if its longer than the original message and echoing back that much data).

Yes, there are a couple references to OpenSSL in cryptoJS (all within [cipher-core.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/source/browse/tags/3.1.2/src/cipher-core.js), but those are merely in response to either using an OpenSSL key format (e.g., its in code defined within cryptoJS with `CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL`) or using an OpenSSL key-derivation-function (`OpenSSLKdf = C_kdf.OpenSSL`).  Note, cryptojs does not link to the OpenSSL library or call the OpenSSL executable.